# Return other value when using Query or Eloquent (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel Eloquent to get data from my table.

```
Ticket::find($ticket_id)
```

The return column will be ticket.id and ticket.state
State is in code like st09.
Is it possible to return actual state name like New York automatically from the eloquent query?

Comment: That depends on your database design. Can you post your database structure?

Comment: The state actual name is in Parameter table.
parameter_name = 'State', type_id = 'st09', type_name='New York'.
Something like this.

Comment: It'd be very helpful to have something like [this](https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=database%20diagram&tt=mzl) or the content of the files containing the `Ticket` and `State` model.